# Where is the beginning of the PATH in Git Bash?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, msysgit, git-bash

On Windows, the `PATH` is separated into 2 parts, the System `PATH` & the User `PATH`. They can both be displayed and changed in the `Control Panel` (though not very well).

While running `msysGit` or `Git for Windows`, a 3rd `PATH` is created and put before the other 2, meaning programs will look in this 3rd `PATH`'s folders for a command before the User or System `PATH` folders. I think `msysGit` created it because I chose the "Run Git and included Unix tools from the `Windows Command Prompt`" option during installation (correct me if I'm wrong):

[image]
Where does `msysGit`/`Git for Windows` store this `PATH`, and how can I change it?

Comment: In all probabilty, the path is stored in the registry - regedit32 should allow you to find it. For a useful FREE tool to edit the user/system PATH, try googling for "path editor".

Comment: @Magoo, Is my answer not showing up yet? Weird, that answer is probably why you saw this.

Comment: It's appearing - I was probably confused by the *nixish filepath - no doubt \etc\profile in Winspeak. Nevertheless, "path editor" is a more useful pointy-clicky tool to manipulate system and user path than that provided with Win... and may obviate the need for a \etc\profile / /etc/profile entry.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is the filename from `Git Bash`'s perspective, not `Windows`'s. `Git Bash` changes the `PATH` to be more *nix-y. In fact, it does this in that same `etc/profile` file. If `msysGit` is at `C:\msysgit`, as it is on my system, `/etc/profile` would in reality be at `C:\msysgit\etc\profile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the `PATH` is in `/etc/profile` (with `/` being wherever `msysGit` or `Git for Windows` is stored). This is similar to how Linux & UNIX do it, with `/etc/profile` being one of the places `Bash` looks for start-up scripts.