# Add PATH via Git Bash (where is the start file?)

Tags: git, bash

I'm installing Laravel Homestead following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrsg2cudfNc

I got stuck at a point where the author of the video says (5:30-6:00):

> "You want to make sure that this directory *~/.composer/vendor/bin* is part of your path. And to do that you'll just open one of your various *start files* like *bashrc* or if you are using *tshell* you can open *zshrc*  [here he says sth I do not understand] be in your home directory if you are on a Mac. So, once you do that you just do something like *export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"*. And that's it. Once you same the file and open a new terminal tab you should have access to Homestead."

So how do I do that?

1. I'm not on Mac. I'm on Windows 8.
2. Should I change the position in the terminal before typing in *PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"*? At the moment I'm in the *learning-laravel-5 folder* - that's the folder inside which I'm installing *Laravel Homestead*. As far as I understand I should change the position and go to *"start file"*. But what is my *"start file"*? Is it *bashrc*, *zshrc* or sth else?
3. I'm doing all that in Git Bash - the author of the video suggest so.

I have a feeling it could have sth to do with this post: [Where is the beginning of the PATH in Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231313/where-is-the-beginning-of-the-path-in-git-bash)

But would appreciate if someone could help me with my own situation.

Comment: Please  [read/view this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/laravel-homestead-on-windows)

Comment: Why? :) That Treehouse course was my first choice but as they are installing the old (I think 4.2 Laravel) in there (and I got stuck there, too - and many other people also) I've switched to Jeffrey Way's instructions at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrsg2cudfNc where Laravel 5 is beeing installed.

Comment: Well, install a software on a Unix is not the same that on a Windows...